# Display 'No Rows' message after applying filter in MUI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**`NoRowsOverlay`** is not working once you apply the filter and as a result there is/are no rows to display.

Here is my code:

```
function customNoRowsOverlay() {
    return (
        <GridOverlay>
            <div>No Rows</div>
        </GridOverlay>
    )
}
```

```
components={{ NoRowsOverlay: customNoRowsOverlay }}
```

I need to display 'No Rows' Message if there is/are no rows to display after applying filter. However the above code works if you have `rows={[]}`

Answer (score 38):

Use the `NoRowsOverlay` slot name if you're using version [@v4.0.0-alpha.18 or above](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/releases/tag/v4.0.0-alpha.18).

If you want to display an overlay when there is no rows in `DataGrid`, you can override [`NoRowsOverlay`](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#no-rows-overlay) or `NoResultsOverlay` slot depending on your usecase:

- `NoRowsOverlay`: Display when there is no row passed to the `DataGrid` (`rows={[]}`).
- `NoResultsOverlay`: Display when there is row data in the `DataGrid`, but the local filter returns no result.

```
<DataGrid
  {...}
  components={{
    NoRowsOverlay: () => (
      <Stack height="100%" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        No rows in DataGrid
      </Stack>
    ),
    NoResultsOverlay: () => (
      <Stack height="100%" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        Local filter returns no result
      </Stack>
    )
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66783261/not-able-to-display-no-rows-message-after-applying-filter-in-react-material-ui]

Comment: For anyone coming across this now, `components` is deprecated in favor of `slots`, and the keys are lowerCamelCase (i.e.: `noRowsOverlay` and `noResultsOverlay`).

Answer (score 6):

If you're only trying to change the default "No rows" text, you can override the `noRowsLabel` with the `localeText` prop.

```
<DataGrid
  {...}
  localeText={{ noRowsLabel: "This is a custom message :)" }}
/>
```

You can read more about the localization settings in [these docs](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/localization/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a separate [slot](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#slots) for that: `NoResultsOverlay`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pro version or any new version of MUI datagrid you can use the following approach.

```
function CustomNoRowsOverlay() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <svg
        width="120"
        height="100"
        viewBox="0 0 184 152"
        aria-hidden
        focusable="false"
      >
        <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
          <g transform="translate(24 31.67)">
            <ellipse
              className="ant-empty-img-5"
              cx="67.797"
              cy="106.89"
              rx="67.797"
              ry="12.668"
            />
            <path
              className="ant-empty-img-1"
              d="M122.034 69.674L98.109 40.229c-1.148-1.386-2.826-2.225-4.593-2.225h-51.44c-1.766 0-3.444.839-4.592 2.225L13.56 69.674v15.383h108.475V69.674z"
            />
            <path
              className="ant-empty-img-2"
              d="M33.83 0h67.933a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v93.344a4 4 0 0 1-4 4H33.83a4 4 0 0 1-4-4V4a4 4 0 0 1 4-4z"
            />
            <path
              className="ant-empty-img-3"
              d="M42.678 9.953h50.237a2 2 0 0 1 2 2V36.91a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H42.678a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V11.953a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zM42.94 49.767h49.713a2.262 2.262 0 1 1 0 4.524H42.94a2.262 2.262 0 0 1 0-4.524zM42.94 61.53h49.713a2.262 2.262 0 1 1 0 4.525H42.94a2.262 2.262 0 0 1 0-4.525zM121.813 105.032c-.775 3.071-3.497 5.36-6.735 5.36H20.515c-3.238 0-5.96-2.29-6.734-5.36a7.309 7.309 0 0 1-.222-1.79V69.675h26.318c2.907 0 5.25 2.448 5.25 5.42v.04c0 2.971 2.37 5.37 5.277 5.37h34.785c2.907 0 5.277-2.421 5.277-5.393V75.1c0-2.972 2.343-5.426 5.25-5.426h26.318v33.569c0 .617-.077 1.216-.221 1.789z"
            />
          </g>
          <path
            className="ant-empty-img-3"
            d="M149.121 33.292l-6.83 2.65a1 1 0 0 1-1.317-1.23l1.937-6.207c-2.589-2.944-4.109-6.534-4.109-10.408C138.802 8.102 148.92 0 161.402 0 173.881 0 184 8.102 184 18.097c0 9.995-10.118 18.097-22.599 18.097-4.528 0-8.744-1.066-12.28-2.902z"
          />
          <g className="ant-empty-img-4" transform="translate(149.65 15.383)">
            <ellipse cx="20.654" cy="3.167" rx="2.849" ry="2.815" />
            <path d="M5.698 5.63H0L2.898.704zM9.259.704h4.985V5.63H9.259z" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <Box sx={{ mt: 1 }}>No Rows</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

    <DataGrid
            slots={{
              noRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
            }}
            {...data}
            rows={[]}
          />
```

Answer (score -3):

When **NoRowsOverlay** is not a top-level property, you can add a custom message like in the example below. For docs, see https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#no-rows-overlay

```
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    components={{
      noRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
    }}
 />
```

[image]